# How to hide an element that cannot be fully displayed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, overflow

I have a Text widget that sometimes can be fully displayed, sometimes not, depending on the widgets around.

If there is not enough space to fully display the widget, I want the widget to not show at all, I don't want it to show partially like with the overflow attribute.

If you know a way to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`LayoutBuilder` to the rescue for you!

> Builds a widget tree that can depend on the parent widget's size.

[Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)

Try this! Play around with the `allowedTextHeightInPixels` value to see how it works.

```
/// Breakpoint or condition to WHEN should we display the Text widget
const allowedTextHeightInPixels = 150.0;
/// Test height for the [Text] widget.
const givenTextHeightByScreenPercentage = 0.3;

class ResponsiveTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveTextWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            print('Text height in pixels: ${constraints.maxHeight * givenTextHeightByScreenPercentage}');
            return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                ),
                if (constraints.maxHeight * givenTextHeightByScreenPercentage > allowedTextHeightInPixels)
                  const SizedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      'Responsive Me',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.2,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do this but i thing `overflow` is good enough for most case, you can also use `Fittedbox` to scale the text with the box with no redundant space.

In case you still want do it, you need to find the `RenderBox` of that specific widget, which will contain its global position and rendered size from `BuildContext`. But `BuildContext` can be not exist if the widget is not rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

If by "fully displayed" you mean that, for example, you have a `SingleChildScrollView` and only half of your `Text` widget is visible, you can try out this library :
https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector.
You can retrieve the visible percentage of your widget with the method `visibilityInfo.visibleFraction`.